# android webview not showing html tabs properly

Tags: android, jquery, html, webview, tabs

In my app , I am having a webview . In webview ,I am showing HTML content which is having  tag ,  .I have 2 tabs in that which should switch on clicking on same place. But in webview they are coming one after the other.

In HTML file, I am calling method of Jquery file that method is not getting called . In browser its working fine. In iOS its working.

I am loading webview with base Url method only.

```
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(pathToHtml, strLoad, "text/html","UTF-8", "");
```

These files are in assets . I am not sure that I am able to provide correct path for jquery files. So , I copied files to sdcard. There I am giving path. So path can not be the issue.

Please help me out . I tried many things but nothing worked. I am not getting what is the issue.

Comment: have you enabled javascript for webview ?

Comment: try to load your custom file in webview.

Comment: Try `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/youFile.html");`

Comment: In pathToHtml I am giving path of HTML file as base URl. previously I was giving path for assets only. But that was not able to find correct path. Now I copied file to sdcard and giving that path like this "/storage/emulated/0/App/tabbed.html"

Comment: My issue get solved. Thanx @ Pratik .
Actually issue was coming in accessing the assets file.

Comment: @vntstudy just upvote to comment to other users can redirect directly that comment

Answer (score 0):

You can call a javascript function from `webView.loadUrl("javascript:testFunction();");` to change the tabs insted of loading the page again. at the first load, you can use `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");` Befor using the jquery code, make sure that javascript enabled, set the webviewclient and webchromeclient for the webView.